# Magento 2 REST API on add to cart "quoteId" is required. Enter and try again

Tags: javascript, cart, rest-api

When I try to add to card any item via REST API I get this error:

```
"{"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"quoteId"}}"
```

First time I get the **cart id** calling this

> "rest/V1/carts/mine"

than I call

> "rest/V1/carts/mine/items"

with this data:

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "24-WG080",
    "qty": 1,
    "quote_id": cartID
  }
}
```

Tried with **cart-item**, **quoteId**, **quote_id** and more...

I'm stuck, I have no ideea what is wrong, the documentation is wrong? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-add-items.html

Enabed developer mode, and now I got this error in response:

```
"#0 [internal function]: Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository->save(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item))
#1 /home2/xxx/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /home2/xxx/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))
#3 /home2/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home2/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#5 /home2/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home2/xxx/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#7 /home2/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 /home2/xxx/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#9 /home2/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#10 /home2/xxx/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#11 {main}"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a request to create the empty cart POST

> {{magento_api_url}}/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/

this will return a token which is the cart ID (e.g 'KZepbhhPiGORreBKqIRlMCywGDTyQtR4')

2. Use that cart ID in the request which adds an item to the cart POST

> {{magento_api_url}}/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/KZepbhhPiGORreBKqIRlMCywGDTyQtR4/items

with the payload similar to what you see below (where quote_id is the key you previously used and the SKU is the SKU of the product you want to add):

```
{
    "cartItem": {
        "qty": 5,
        "sku": "24-UG06"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Below Reference.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-quote.html

Comment: guest cart works, the one for logged in users doesn't

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of missing context in this question but the **short answer** is no, the documentation you mention is not wrong, you are probably not sending `Authorization: Bearer <customer token>` in the headers.

The **long and detailed answer** is...

Check `vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml`. Almost all the `/V1/carts/mine` API endpoints have the following:

```
<data>
    <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
</data>
```

The `force="true"` property set any parameter with it (`cartId` in this case) as `null`. This is being made by `vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamsOverrider.php`.

The `override` method iterates over the params received in your API request and the following lines overrides the provided value by null:

```
public function override(array $inputData, array $parameters)
{
    foreach ($parameters as $name => $paramData) {
        ...
        if ($paramData[Converter::KEY_FORCE] || !$this->isNestedArrayValueSet($inputData, $arrayKeys)) {
            ...
            if (isset($this->paramOverriders[$paramValue])) {
                $value = $this->paramOverriders[$paramValue]->getOverriddenValue();
            } ...
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

`$paramData[Converter::KEY_FORCE]` is what the XML sent previously mentioned (`force="true"`).

In the particular case of `/V1/carts/mine/` endpoints, the `cartId` value is set as `null` because it is intended to be retrieved from the context. You can see this implementation at `vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Webapi/ParamOverriderCartId.php`:

```
public function getOverriddenValue()
{
    try {
        if ($this->userContext->getUserType() === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER) {
            $customerId = $this->userContext->getUserId();

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface */
            $cart = $this->cartManagement->getCartForCustomer($customerId);
            if ($cart) {
                return $cart->getId();
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Current customer does not have an active cart.'));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Having said that, the solution is to avoid using `/V1/carts/mine` without sending customer token as a header.

Use `/V1/carts/{cartId}` endpoints instead. In your case, use `/V1/carts/{cartId}/items/{itemId}` to add/update the specified cart item.

**Please be aware**, on any interaction with the cart/quote via API... Provide `quote_id` into the body of the request for endpoints which mentions this value in the Adobe Commerce's documentation. For example:

```
POST https://www.example.com/rest/V1/carts/INSERT_QUOTE_ID_VALUE/items

{
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "INSERT_SKU_VALUE",
        "qty": 1,
        "quote_id": "INSERT_QUOTE_ID_VALUE"
    }
}
```